# Какими способами можно решить проблему с шириной строк?

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

Прошу Ваших советов в реализации данной задачи.

[image]

Я реализовал анимацию с помощью svg, но тут-то и возникла проблема с шириной строк.

```css
svg {
  width: 315px;
  height: 44px;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 fill: none;
 stroke: black;
 stroke-width: 1;
  overflow: visible
}

.btn_wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 315px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: red;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.animated-line {
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <polyline class='animated-line' points="135,22 135,0 0,0 0,44 300,44"/>
  <a href="#">Каталог</a>
</svg>

  <a href="#" class="btn_wrap">Каталог</a>
```

`stroke-width` отличается от `border`, а при адаптиве или при увеличении/уменьшении масштаба некоторые элементы svg рамки, становятся как `border`:

[image]

Comment: Вам как надо сделать, чтобы при уменьшении, увеличении `border `и  `.animated-line` были одинаковой толщины?

Comment: надо чтобы всегда толщина линии была 1 пиксель , можно сравнить с бордером в 1 пиксель, а сейчас в svg она на все 3 px тянет (

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Короткий ответ:*

SVG `stroke`  рисуется от осевой линии симметрично: если ширина линии - `stroke-width="1px"`, то полпикселя будет выше осевой, вторая половина пикселя будет ниже осевой. Это для горизонтальной линии. Для вертикальной линии соответственно будет полпикселя влево и вправо от осевой.  У вас форма фигуры совпадает с границами SVG и поэтому от трех линий вычитается по полпикселя, а хвостик, который вы обвели красным показывается целиком, поэтому он выглядит более жирным.

Я открыл ваш файл (без анимаций, чисто svg код) в векторном редакторе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*серая линия это граница svg*, что выходит за её пределы,- будет отрезано. Вы видите три линии шириной только по полпикселя. Вертикальный хвостик получается шириной `1px`. 
Тут ещё вмешивается эффект полупиксельного размытия для трех сторон, которые идут по границе SVG документа, поэтому линии не чёрные, а серые.

**Решение**

- Увеличить высоту документа SVG минимум на `2px` - `height: 46px;`
- так как фигура всё равно останется прилипать кверху и влево, сдвинуть
  её вправо и вниз на `1px`

`transform="translate(1 1)"`

*Ниже полный код решения:*

```css
svg {
  width: 315px;
  height: 46px;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 fill: none;
 stroke: black;
 stroke-width: 1px;
   overflow: visible; 
   
}

.btn_wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 315px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: red;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.animated-line {
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg  width="315px"   height="46px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
  <polyline transform="translate(1 1)" fill="none" stroke="black" class='animated-line' points="135,22 135,0 0,0 0,44 300,44"/>

  <a href="#">Каталог</a>
</svg>

  <a href="#" class="btn_wrap">Каталог</a>
```

*Более подробно*

Для того, чтобы не было потом проблем с кроссбраузерностью и мучений с позиционированием, когда встречаются `svg` и `css` элементы, в вашем случае это рамка `svg` и надпись `css` - каталог, а также ссылка на каталог, лучше всего это сделать внутри svg.

Поверьте, это не трудно, зато у вас никогда не распадется вёрстка и вам не придется мучительно долго искать причину.

- Для добавления текста в svg имеется команда `<text>`. Параметры
  текста вы можете задавать на выбор, как внутри svg, так и во внешней
  таблице `css`. Но определитесь сразу, лучше не дублировать стили.

В этом примере стили задаются внутри svg

`<text x="10" y="30" font-size="24px" fill="none" font-family="serif" font-weight="900"   > КАТАЛОГ </text>`

Для управлениями стилями из внешней таблицы CSS необходимо добавить в первую строчку svg файла полный путь до внешней таблицы стилей.

`<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>`

- Ссылку можно разместить внутри svg, например ссылкой будет текст.

### Update

*по комментариям автора вопроса*

Добавлено масштабирование, то есть адаптивность к любому размеру экрана

```
width:25%;  
   height:25%;
```

**Уменьшая, увеличивая эти проценты вы можете увеличивать, уменьшать изображение svg и тем самым изменять визуально толщину линий.**
Скопируйте код из этого сниппета на свой ПК, так как сниппет немного искажает восприятие реального изображения.

*Ниже полный код приложения с текстом в качестве ссылки внутри SVG*

```css
svg {
   width:25%;  
   height:25%;
  top: 0;
 left: 0;
 fill: none;
 stroke: black;
 stroke-width: 1px;
   overflow: visible;
}

svg #textK {
  font-size:24px;
  font-family:serif;
  font-weight:500; 
  stroke:none;
  fill:black;
 vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;
  
}

.animated-line {
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?> 
<svg   viewBox="0 0 315 46" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  >
  <polyline transform="translate(1 1)"   class='animated-line' points="135,22 135,0 0,0 0,44 300,44"/>
<a href="#"  >  
 <text id="textK" x="10" y="30"    > КАТАЛОГ </text>
 </a>   
</svg>
```

Дополнительный бонус,- текст ссылки внутри svg индексируется поисковиками.

Ссылку можно сделать на весь блок SVG

```
 <a href="https://#">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?> 
<svg  width="315px"   height="46px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
  <polyline transform="translate(1 1)"   vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" class='animated-line' points="135,22 135,0 0,0 0,44 300,44"/>

 <text id="textK" x="10" y="30"    > КАТАЛОГ </text>

</svg>
 </a>
```

Comment: скажите пожалуйста, каким редактором для svg вы пользуетесь?

Comment: @kizoso в основном Inkscape

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, я всегда думал, что ты в ручную пишешь код `svg`

Comment: @Air ну когда простая кривая, то вручную, так быстрее, и в этом примере вручную написать без проблем, а редактор открыл и скрин снял, чтобы наглядно показать, как всё выглядит

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, ну значит все же в ручную... Редакторы для `svg` и библиотеки для `js`, это зло)))))

Comment: @Air спасибо, у меня немного другой взгляд,- сначала нужно досконально понять, как это можно сделать вручную, например спрайты, морфинг, все виды анимации, а потом уже, когда знаешь, что точно должно получиться на выходе использовать библиотеки, фреймворки, а не тыкать вслепую, "затачивать под себя" :) В svg в некоторых случаях можно затыкаться насмерть и не добиться результата. Хотя всё просто - математика, хоть за 5 класс, но математика и понимание, как работает viewBox

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, вот и я об этом... По этому и говорю, что зло. Когда хорошо знаешь `js`, вот тогда у тебя есть право лениться и использовать библиотеки...   Я вот ни как не возьмусь за `svg` вплотную... )))

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но толщина линии такая же, а надо 1 пиксель, такое реально сделать  ?

Comment: @Bohdan а чем вы меряете 1px у вас или не 1px,- на глаз? Ширина линии задана явно width="1px"  Главное, что у вас теперь все 4 линии фигуры одной толщины, а не толстый отросток и три тонкие линии.   Я не стал играться с маштабированием, хотя можно попробовать,- тогда линии будут выглядеть тоньше. Вы в принципе поняли ответ, как всё это работает?

Comment: @Bohdan добавил масштабирование. Пример ниже **Update** Теперь вам все карты в руки, настраиваете изображение на свой вкус Если  мой ответ был вам полезен, не забудьте пожалуйста поставить + и чекбокс напротив цифр.

Comment: Информация была полезна, но это все равно не то, не так как на макете.

Я сделал данную реализацию другим путем, не используя свг. При уменьшении масштаба svg, цвет все равно не тот. Он более серый

Comment: @Bohdan Спасибо. Серый цвет получается при уменьшении так как,- это эффект пиксилизации по границам цветов. Он особенно виден когда чёрная линия на белом. Я понял, что у вас получилось другим способом, но svg очень трендовое направление особенно на западе. Осваивайте его потихоньку. Может на цветном фоне, линии svg будут нормального чёрного цвета.